# GeoCoordinateWatcher Latitude and Longitude to Label

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code below I got from one of the forums, I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude of a client computer (user).
But it is returning me an unknown location.
Did I need to add or change from this.

```
public string GetUserLocation()
{
    string coords = "";
    GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
    watcher.Start(); 
    GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;
    if (!watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
    {
        double lat = coord.Latitude;
        double longi = coord.Longitude;  
        coords = lat + "," + longi;
    }
    else
    {
        return coords="Unknown latitude and longitude.";
    }
    return coords;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `watcher.TryStart` to see if your watcher is being initialized correctly?

```
bool started = watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
if (!started)
{
   Console.WriteLine("GeoCoordinateWatcher timed out on start.");
}
```

Also check the Status and Permission of [GeoCoordinateWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The Status property can be checked to determine if data is available.
>   If data is available, you can get the location one time from the
>   Position property, or receive continuous location updates by handling
>   the PositionChanged event.
>
> The Permission, Status, and Position properties support
>   INotifyPropertyChanged, so that an application can data-bind to these
>   properties.

This is how to check the permission:

```
if (watcher.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Granted)
{
   // you have permission... 
}
```

And you can [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.status(v=vs.110).aspx) for checking the status.

Comment: in this line i can  see my coordinates :watcher.Position.Location but when its reach to checking becoming unknown.